# CSS: How to set hover effect on menu-item when submenu-item is displayed

Tags: html, css

Sorry with title if it is not looks bad, I don't know how can I write the title for my issue.

So I have a menu bar with some menu-items and submenu-items as:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a class="current" href="">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Submenu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Submenu2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Menu3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk2HA/) of what I have done so far.

What I want is to keep the *menu-item* also in `:hover` state if its *submenu-item* is being hover, such as If my mouse is on `submenu` or `submenu2` the `Menu2` should also be *darkened*. How can I do this with CSS?

I hope I am clear with my question.

EDIT:

Wooo thanks a lot every-one.

got it with: `#menu li:hover`

```
#menu li:hover,#menu a:hover,#menu > li a.current{

} ​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In last line of your CSS, add `#menu li:hover` to target selectors

Updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7UaNn/

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this by hooking up to the `:hover` state of the parent `li` element instead of the anchor element - which is a children of the list-item that is actually hovered - like so:

```
li a:hover,
li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

You might need to use [:nth-child()](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) to get around every sublink being in hover state. Did not test this.

/edit: updated the selector, now using > a to only select the direct child anchor element of the hovered list element, no need for :nth-child or the like.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment all you hoverstyles for the listitem are applied to the `a`- Element.

However, you need to apply them to the `li`-Element to keep the hover state active.

Sometimes that may become tricky, but in your case it's pretty easy, just add:

```
#menu > li:hover{
 background:#474747;   
}
```

to your styles.

See **[your modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk2HA/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add this `#menu li:hover > a` in the following css

```
#menu a:hover, #menu > li a.current {
  // your Style
}
```

So it should look like this:

```
 #menu a:hover, #menu > li a.current, #menu li:hover > a {
  // your Style
}
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/bk2HA/7/

Answer (score 1):

Along with "a" also add hover for "li" :

```
#menu > li:hover{
background:#474747;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the thing that is changed on hover the background of the LI rather than the background of the 'a'.

```
ul#menu li:hover { background:#000; }
```